# JAXB Unable To Handle Attribute with Colon (:) in name?

Tags: attributes, jaxb, dtd, unmarshalling

I am attempting to use JAXB to unmarshall an XML files whose schema is defined by a DTD (ugh!).

The external provider of the DTD has specified one of the element attributes as `xml:lang`:

```
<!ATTLIST langSet
id ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

This comes into the xjc-generated class (standard generation; no *.xjb magic) as:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "xml:lang", required = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
protected String xmlLang;
```

However, when unmarshalling valid XML files with JAXB, the `xmlLang` attribute is always `null`.

When I edited the XML file, replacing `xml:lang` with `lang` and changed the `@XmlAttribute` to match, unmarshalling was successful (i.e. attributes were non-`null`).

I did find this http://old.nabble.com/unmarshalling-ignores-element-attribute-%27xml%27-td22558466.html.  But, the resolution there was to convert to XML Schema, etc.  My strong preference is to go straight from an un-altered DTD (since it is externally provided and defined by an ISO standard).

Is this a JAXB bug?  Am I missing something about "namespaces" in attribute names?

FWIW, `java -version` = "build 1.6.0_20-b02" and `xjc -version` = "xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6""

Comment: Which DTD is this? `xml:lang` is an XML Schema meta-attribute, so the DTD is describing something that originated from a Schema, which would suggest to me that there's a full schema out there.

Comment: AFAIK, the publisher only makes a DTD available.  It would hard to image that they publish a DTD based on an Schema but don't make the latter available.  However, I've had the author of some related tools ask me if I'm using a Schema to generate the JAXB objects, so there might be something out there...

Comment: Thanks for the nabble link. You made my life easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing replacing `xml:` with a `namespace` declaration in the JAXB-generated class:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", required = true)
```

Which makes sense, in a way.

Without this kind of guidance, how would JAXB know how to interpret the otherwise-undefined namespace `xml:`?  Unless, of course, it implemented some special-case internal handling to `xml:` as done in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getNamespaceURI%28java.lang.String%29 (see the first **NOTE:**)

Whether it's a bug in `xjc`'s generation of the annotated objects or a bug in the unmarhaller, or simply requires a mapping somewhere in the `xjc` process is still an open question in my mind.

For now, it's working and all it requires is a little `xjc` magic, so I'm reasonably happy.

Comment: Awesome, it took me hours of research! :D

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: Although 8 years late, I am adding this answer for lost souls such as myself trying to understand auto generation of java files from a DTD.*

You can set project wide namespaces for the unmarshaller to work with directly in the project-info.java file via the @XmlSchema option.

This file should be automatically generated by xjc when generating classes from a schema, however it appears **xjc does not automatically generate the package-info.java file when generating from a DTD!**

However, you can manually make this file, and add it to the same package as the files generated by xjc.

The file would look like the following:

**package-info.java :**

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, 
    xmlns = {
            @XmlNs(prefix="xlink", namespaceURI="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="namespace2", namespaceURI="http://www.w3c.org/1999/namespace2")
    }) 

package your.generated.package.hierarchy;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

You can add as many namespaces as required, simply add a new line in the form:

```
@XmlNs(prefix="namespace", namespaceURI="http://www.uri.to.namespace.com")
```

The benefit of doing it this way, rather than compared to editing the generated `@XmlAttribute` is that you do not need to change each generated XmlAttribute, and you do not need to manually remove the namespaces from the XmlAttribute name variable.